# How to display one form element near to another element in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my active admin page i have link for manage users. In manage users page I have email option for some categories. Name of the category and email or displayed in the next line. I want them to be display nearly.

Example:

```
  send new item arrival
           email   yes
                   no
```

yes and no has radio button.
I want this to be displayed as

```
      send new item arrival    email   yes
                                       no
```

manage_user.html.erb

```
  <%= form.label :"send new item arrival" %>

  <% if email %>
    <%= form.input :send new item arrival_has_email", :label => 'email', :as => :radio, :collection => {:Yes => true, :No => false}%>
  <% end %>
```

**EDITED** code

```
<style>

body.active_admin .user ol {
    margin-left: 50px;

}
body.active_admin .user ol label{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5e6469;
    display: inline;
}
body.active_admin .user ol li ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10%;
    display: inline;

}
body.active_admin .user ol li ol li{

    margin: 0.1em 3.5em 0.5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

body.active_admin form .actions{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0
}
body.active_admin .user ol label.title {
    background: #087B85;
    color: #ffffff;
}

</style>
```

By this i got

```
send new item arrival
       email   yes  no
```

Comment: This is nor Rails, it's CSS issue. Did you write a proper CSS class for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is CSS issue.
Just make something like

```
<div class="pull-left">
     <%= form.label :"send new item arrival" %>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">    
      <% if email %>
        <%= form.input :send new item arrival_has_email", :label => 'email', :as => :radio, :collection => {:Yes => true, :No => false}%>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

And user proper CSS styles